# How can I get a non-main PHP file to load when my WordPress plugin loads?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin that has a dependency on a second plugin, `OtherPlugin`. I have a non-main PHP file in my plugin's directory that I need to be loaded in order to register for a hook in `OtherPlugin`. My problem is that this file doesn't seem to be getting loaded (error logs aren't getting printed and the desired side effects aren't getting performed.)

I've tried using the `--require='path_to_b.php'` global parameter described [here](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/) but am running into dependency problems, since my class, `B`, inherits from an `OtherPlugin` class, `A`:

```
Fatal error: Class 'A' not found in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/b.php
```

The solution can't be to `--require` the entire class hierarchy in reverse order, but I don't see another way out of this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in your case, `B extends A` (A being from otherPlugin) but when B is being declared in b.php, the file a.php has not been loaded by otherPlugin yet.

The workaround is to use `require_once('full_path_to_a.php')` at the top of `b.php` before B class declaration. This will load a.php so that class A is now available for B to extend.

You may need add additional `require_once` to other files containing class A's dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still having the same problem, though -- PHP doesn't know about the superclass, `A`, even when deferring until `wp_loaded` to instantiate `B`. `OtherPlugin` offers its own hook, `other_plugin_hook`, where it's expecting me to register my `init`, but that fails with the same error too.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether your superclass A has its own namespace?

Comment: It's defined in a separate plugin, with an `@package OtherPlugin` annotation at the top of the file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Does the php file containing the B class declaration have the words `namespace` right at the top of the page?

Comment: I also noticed that I might have misunderstood when you say `--require`. For some reason I thought you meant using the php command `require("path_to_my_file.php")` in your b.php. Regardless, have you tried doing it this way, placing it at the top of your b.php instead of calling it in the cmd line?

Comment: The file with the `B` class declaration doesn't have a `namespace`, no. The problem seems to be that `b.php` isn't being loaded, and if I put a `require "path_to_b.php"` in `myplugin.php`, I get a fatal error saying `A not found`. It seems that `require B`  -- either by adding the statement to `myplugin.php` or using the global parameter in a setup script -- will fail because of the undefined superclass, `A`, in `OtherPlugin`.

I know when `b.php` is being loaded because I have an error log at the top of the file. It loads / prints if I put the file in a subdirectory of `OtherPlugin`.

Comment: Say the superclass A is in file `a.php`. (1) How are you loading `a.php`? Or is it in a plugin that is already loaded in Wordpress? (2) And is there a `namespace` at the top of `a.php`?

Comment: `a.php` is a file contained in a subdirectory of `OtherPlugin`, and I'm installing / activating `OtherPlugin` from the setup shell script. My plugin gets activated afterward within the same script. And no, there's no `namespace` at the top of `a.php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193461/discussion-between-chatnoir-and-jefflovejapan).